# C++ Template enum T for functiun return type

Tags: c++, templates, enums

i'm trying to have a template class that will call the adequate function for each Enum.

I Have 3 Enum :
`M_EnumA` from class `AAA`, `M_EnumB` from class `BBB` and `M_EnumC` from class `CCC`.

My main class is like that

```
#pragma once

#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

#include "AAA.h"
#include "BBB.h"
#include "CCC.h"

template<typename T>
class Header
{
public :
   Header();

  void Hello(T param);

  AAA::M_EnumA retHello(AAA::M_EnumA e);
  BBB::M_EnumB retHello(BBB::M_EnumB e);
  CCC::M_EnumC retHello(CCC::M_EnumC e);
};
#endif
```

```
template<typename T>
Header<T>::Header()
{
  std::cout << "cst" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Header<T>::Hello(T param)
{
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
  std::cout << retHello(param) << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
AAA::M_EnumA Header<T>::retHello(AAA::M_EnumA e)
{
  std::cout << "AAA" << std::endl;
  return e;
}

template<typename T>
BBB::M_EnumB Header<T>::retHello(BBB::M_EnumB e)
{
  std::cout << "BBB" << std::endl;
  return e;
}

template<typename T>
CCC::M_EnumC Header<T>::retHello(CCC::M_EnumC e)
{
  std::cout << "CCC" << std::endl;
  return e;
}
```

And my main is like that

```
int main()
{
  AAA::M_EnumA a = AAA::M_EnumA::A1;

  Header<AAA::M_EnumA> *header = new Header<AAA::M_EnumA>();
  Header<BBB::M_EnumB> *headerb = new Header<BBB::M_EnumB>();;
  Header<CCC::M_EnumC> *headerc = new Header<CCC::M_EnumC>();

  header->Hello(a);
  headerb->Hello(BBB::A1);
  headerc->Hello(CCC::A1);

  return 0;
}
```

But i got **error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol** in my main and i can't understand why.
Sorry for this beginner question.

Comment: Have you put definition of template in cpp files? Then this is wrong.

Comment: You have memleak with `Header<AAA::M_EnumA> *header = new Header<AAA::M_EnumA>();` whereas it could simply be `Header<AAA::M_EnumA> header;`